# Topology Checking issue in Qgis 2.14.1

Tags: topology, snapping, digitizing, geometric-network, validation

I am working on a large data set of Road with snapping tolerance 5px with topological editing option enable. When i am zooming to the snapped vertex with zoom level upto 1:50, its looking snapped or if moving the vertex then all snapped vertex are moving together .

After this i should be confident that snapping option has set correctly. But when i am checking the same dataset with topological checker tool of Qgis 2.14.1Essen with option of dangling nodes. There are lot of error showing in dataset apart from the ends of road. Why this happening . I am not able to get whether problem is with tool or my snapping tollerance settings.

Comment: I experience this (2.18). I've been able to remove the dangling ends by moving the shared vertex a little bit. I've been assuming this is a bug rather than that it's my lack of understanding. I'd like to know if the problem remains on QGIS 3.